# AzAPI schema_validation_enabled bug

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azapi

why isn't `ignore_body_changes` working for AzApi Terraform provider. (am I doing something wrong?)

```
│ Error: embedded schema validation failed: the `body` is invalid:
│ `properties.template.containers.0.resources.ephemeralStorage` is not expected here, it's read only
│ `properties.template.containers.1.resources.ephemeralStorage` is not expected here, it's read only
│  You can try to update `azapi` provider to the latest version or disable the validation using the feature flag `schema_validation_enabled = false` within the resource block
│ 
│   with azapi_resource.job,
│   on main.tf line 58, in resource "azapi_resource" "job":
│   58: resource "azapi_resource" "job" {
```

https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi/releases shows that in version 1.9.0 they added `ignore_body_changes`

I've tried both `1.9.0` and `1.10.0` to create an [Azure Container App Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/jobs?tabs=azure-resource-manager) and in both cases, the plan / apply works and creates my job, using the the MS provided starter image:

```
resource "azapi_resource" "job" {
  type = "Microsoft.App/jobs@2023-05-01"
  name = local.job_name
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  body = jsonencode({
   "properties": {
      "configuration": {
          "manualTriggerConfig": {
              "parallelism": 1,
              "replicaCompletionCount": 1
          },
          "replicaRetryLimit": 0,
          "replicaTimeout": 30,
          "triggerType": "Manual"
      },
      "environmentId": "${data.azurerm_container_app_environment.ace.id}",
      "template": {
          "containers": [
              {
                  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/k8se/quickstart-jobs:latest",
                  "name": "main",
                  "resources": {
                      "cpu": 0.25,
                      "memory": "0.5Gi"
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
    } 
  })

  response_export_values    = ["*"]
  schema_validation_enabled = false
  
  ignore_body_changes       = [
    "properties.configuration",
    "properties.environmentId",
    "properties.template"
  ]

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
}
```

After resource creation, the source code pipeline [updates the configuration using the AZ CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-update).  In my case, I'm adding a second image as a sidecar and updating the main image, both of which are references to images in my ACR... and that all works.

The issue is that if I then replan or attempt to destory the resource in Terraform, I get the error referenced above.

I created [issue 382 on the AzApi provider](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi/issues/382), but was curious if anyone here had suggestions around how I can avoid the issue.

Maybe I'm just doing something wrong???

Comment: Terraform maintains a record of the state of the infrastructure it manages. If you modify the infrastructure outside of Terraform, (using Azure CLI), Terraform state will become inconsistent with the actual infrastructure. Terraform will not know about the external changes, so it will not be able to alter or delete the resource when you run commands

Comment: Which is why I set "ignore_changes = all"

Comment: With Ignore_changes you can only stop altering the info, but deleting a resource that consists of a resource created outside Terraform is impossible.

Comment: not trying to delete anything....I'm trying to make subsequent plans ignore changes....this works perfectly for other resources...and according to the AzApi docs, should work for that provider as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out, I just needed to explicitly ignore template.container changes:

```
  ignore_body_changes       = [
    "properties.template.containers",
    "properties.configuration",
    "properties.template"
  ]
```

https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi/issues/382#issuecomment-1853203032

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision AzAPI schema_validation and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The `ignore_body_changes` attribute, introduced in version 1.9.0 of the `azapi` provider, is supposed to allow you to specify parts of the resource body that Terraform should ignore during the plan and apply phases.

The error message suggests that the `ephemeralStorage` property is read-only and shouldn't be included in the `body` of the resource.

Try removing or adjusting the part of your configuration that references `ephemeralStorage` to see if that resolves the issue.

As mentioned, I tried the demo configuration based on the information provider using main and sidecar images.

**My demo Terraform configuration:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
      version = "1.10.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azapi" {
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vksb"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "acctest-01"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "example" {
  name                       = "vk-environment"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
}

# Azure Container App Job
resource "azapi_resource" "job" {
  type    = "Microsoft.App/jobs@2023-05-01"
  name    = "vksbjob111"
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  location = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      configuration = {
        manualTriggerConfig = {
          parallelism = 1,
          replicaCompletionCount = 1
        },
        replicaRetryLimit = 0,
        replicaTimeout = 30,
        triggerType = "Manual"
      },
      environmentId = "${azurerm_container_app_environment.example.id}",
      template = {
        containers = [
          {
            image = "myacr.azurecr.io/main-app:v1",  # Main container image
            name = "main",
            resources = {
              cpu = 0.25,
              memory = "0.5Gi"
            }
          },
          {
            image = "myacr.azurecr.io/sidecar-app:v1",  # Sidecar container image
            name = "sidecar",
            resources = {
              cpu = 0.25,
              memory = "0.5Gi"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  })

  response_export_values    = ["*"]
  schema_validation_enabled = false
  
   ignore_body_changes       = [
    "properties.configuration",
    "properties.environmentId",
    "properties.template"
  ]

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

Now I try to make changes in the main configuration and make the sidecar parameters with default values and with the parameters

```
response_export_values    = ["*"]
  schema_validation_enabled = false
  
   ignore_body_changes       = [
    "properties.configuration",
    "properties.environmentId",
    "properties.template"
  ]

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
```

and rerunning the steps of terraform and check if terraform is able to skip the changes that you make.

```
  resources = {
              cpu = 0.50,
              memory = "1Gi"
            }
```

**terraform plan:**

[image]

**terraform destroy:**

[image]